# Segmentation fault when calling sdp_record_register()

Tags: linux, bluetooth, segmentation-fault, bluez

I'm trying to register my Bluetooth service in SDP using BlueZ. I follow [this](http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x604.html) tutorial. Code compiles successfully but when I run it, I get a segmentation fault (even with the code copy-pasted from the tutorial).

Part of stack trace:

```
{   "address": 140382101864854
,   "build_id": "a629c43f58d471aa12e35d3e63ee264c514a21ac"
,   "build_id_offset": 86422
,   "function_name": "sdp_device_record_register_binary"
,   "file_name": "/lib64/libbluetooth.so.3"
}
, {   "address": 140382101865504
,   "build_id": "a629c43f58d471aa12e35d3e63ee264c514a21ac"
,   "build_id_offset": 87072
,   "function_name": "sdp_device_record_register"
,   "file_name": "/lib64/libbluetooth.so.3"
}
, {   "address": 140382101865738
,   "build_id": "a629c43f58d471aa12e35d3e63ee264c514a21ac"
,   "build_id_offset": 87306
,   "function_name": "sdp_record_register"
,   "file_name": "/lib64/libbluetooth.so.3"
}
```

Did anyone have the same problem?

Comment: It would help you get an answer if you posted the code that is failing along with as much context as you can provide.

Comment: What's the Bluez version? You should not use SDP to do this from Bluez5. We have `ProfileManager` interface for this in DBUS.

Comment: I tried exact the same code as sample code from tutorial, that's why I haven't posted it here.
You're right Parthiban, I'm using BlueZ 5.50. I haven't noticed that it had changed the way to register services. Thank you so much!

Comment: @dluuugi Bluez5 in Linux as a Daemon provide DBUS interface to do things. You can find its documentation in Bluez source `doc` directory. But you can also use `libbluetooth` socket based implementation, but AFAIK this is discouraged to do so.

Comment: So how can I do this using libbluetooth? I thought that actually sdp_record_register should be used for that.

Answer (score 1):

This segmentation fault is coming from broken sdptool in Bluez 5.

Solution for this is given in answer for following Raspberry Pi stackoverflow question.

[Failed to connect to SDP server on FF:FF:FF:00:00:00: No such file or directory](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/41776)

Comment: You can't that Bluez5 is broken. This was intentionally removed.

Comment: I added `--compat` like that link says and my `sdp_record_register` still crashes.